# Vue component methods not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying out Vue and I ran into the issue of a component's "mounted" method not firing, I honestly can't see any reason why it won't work, there are no errors or warnings, I checked every single line at least 4 times now, and I just can't figure out what's wrong, I tried "console-logging" something when the method fires in a Post component and it worked, but it didn't when I tried doing the same thing in a Comment component, here is all the code you should need:

The Post component:

```
<template>
  <div class="blog-post">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
    <div class="comment-section">
      <Comment
        v-for="comment in comments"
        v-bind:key="comment.id"
        :name="comment.name"
        :email="comment.email"
        :body="comment.body"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Comment from "./Comment";

export default {
  name: "Post",
  props: {
    title: String,
    body: String,
    postId: Number,
  },
  components: {
    Comment,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      comments: [
        {
          name: "comment name",
          email: "comment email",
          body: "comment body",
          postId: 1,
          id: 1,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getPostData() {
      const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data;
      this.comments = data.map((comment) => ({
        name: comment.name,
        email: comment.email,
        body: comment.body,
        postId: comment.postId,
        id: comment.id,
      }));
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getPostData();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And the Comment component:

```
<template>
  <div class="comment">
    <h4>{{ name }}</h4>
    <h5>{{ email }}</h5>
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Comment",
  props: {
    name: String,
    email: String,
    body: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
};
</script>
```

The comments render properly when I put that placeholder data myself into the comments array, so apparently the mount() and the getPostData() methods aren't firing (or one of them at least), considering I also tried console-logging as I've said before. I can't see what the issue here is at all and can't really google stuff like this since it's so specific. So far what I know is that, the API I'm fetching data from works, the URL is correct, the comments do display on the page, meaning it's not a problem with rendering, and as I said I've tried console-logging something in the getPostData and it didn't work, whereas in Blog component it did (which does exactly the same Post should do, except fetches Posts instead of Comments). In any case, any help would be appreciated, I hope I gave all the info you might need, if not, please ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mounted` function is inside your `methods` object.
Move it out like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="blog-post">
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ body }}</p>
    <div class="comment-section">
      <Comment
        v-for="comment in comments"
        v-bind:key="comment.id"
        :name="comment.name"
        :email="comment.email"
        :body="comment.body"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import Comment from "./Comment";

export default {
  name: "Post",
  props: {
    title: String,
    body: String,
    postId: Number,
  },
  components: {
    Comment,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      comments: [
        {
          name: "comment name",
          email: "comment email",
          body: "comment body",
          postId: 1,
          id: 1,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getPostData() {
      const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const data = await response.data;
      this.comments = data.map((comment) => ({
        name: comment.name,
        email: comment.email,
        body: comment.body,
        postId: comment.postId,
        id: comment.id,
      }));
    },
  },
  mounted() {
      this.getPostData();
    },
};
</script>
```